# How to customize the Office PickerDialog

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I'd like to use the Office PickerDialog to select a user and get their UserPrincipalName. The dialog shows Groups and I'd like to filter them out. Is it possible?
The documentation is woefully inadequate..

My code:

```
var dlg = application.PickerDialog;
dlg.DataHandlerId = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MsoPeopleDataHandler.PeopleDataHandler").GUID.ToString("B");
dlg.Title = "Select user";
var props = dlg.Properties;
var prop = props.Add("SiteUrl", SharePointSiteUrl, MsoPickerField.msoPickerFieldText);
var existingResults = dlg.CreatePickerResults();
dynamic results = dlg.Show(false, existingResults);
if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
{
    var id = (string)results.Item[0].Id;
    var userPrincipalName = id.Substring(id.LastIndexOf('|') + 1);
}
```